# Ubuntu 20.04 Install not booting in AMD Ryzen 7 (UEFI 8450M Gaming P1)

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, amd-ryzen

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 (as well as 18.04) in the system described above multiple times but after a short boot of the USB loader the screen just goes blank (See images). I've tried changing the secure boot options in the UEFI with no luck. I'm currently running Windows 10 as my main OS.

Anyone having the same problem? any advice?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you checked your vendor site that your BIOS/firmware is updated to the latest?  That can eliminate many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the splash-screen get stuck. Have you tried to press ALT-F1 or ALT-F2? Mostly you will see login prompt then.